# .htaccess with php hidden parameters and language selection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to get my .htaccess file to route the urls to my site correctly. I have a number of languages people can choose from wanting URL's like:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/
http://www.domain.com/en/contact
```

But I can't seem to get the page 'contact' working when writing a rule to get the 'en' variable.

```
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/ index.php?language=$1
```

I use that to grab the language code but how could I get the contact page to work?

**EDIT:**

Apparently I needed some QSA option but now the language get variable grabs contact as the variable with the en

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

With this rule the site:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/contact
```

Returns:

```
en/contact
```

**EDIT2**

What I am trying to accomplish is the directory structure:

```
/
/contact
/about
```

Having these folders in the root but grabbing and ignoring the /en/ language variable. So I don't need a second variable for &page=contact, I need it to route into the directory folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining your two expressions, although you need to modify the second group - `[0-9]+` will only match numbers, not words like `contact`. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `QSA` option allows a query string to be appended to the clean URL, perhaps something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/contact?to=support&subject=Hello
```

---

In response to your comment, this expression should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ $2/index.php?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In the rewritten rule, `$2` holds `contact`, for example, and `$1` holds `en`. The former is used as the directory, and the latter as an argument in the query string.

Comment: Fixed the numbers to general thanks, but read my edit2 for clarification.

Comment: Are you trying to get, for example, `/en/contact` to go to `/contact/index.php?args=here`, or are you trying to get from `/en/contact` to just `/contact` in your rewrite?

Comment: Essentially this: /en/contact to go to /contact/index.php?language=$1